# Retrieving the search query from child Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a mother Activity which contains 3-4 child Fragment. I followed the code of Fragment code of tutorial site Android Hive.

This is the Main Activity:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.nordicsoft.dilosysNewVersion.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.nordicsoft.dilosysNewVersion.model.NavDrawerItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getOverflowMenu();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment_NewsFeed();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment_Coupons();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment_Deals();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment_Events();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Fragment_Locations();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Fragment_Shop();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
       private void getOverflowMenu() {

            try {
               ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
               Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
               if(menuKeyField != null) {
                   menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                   menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
}
```

And this is one of the Child:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment_Locations extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_Locations(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The Search in the Menu:

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Now I want to access the search (from the Action-bar which comes from the menu) query (the value that has been written in the search box) from multiple child of this Project and each will perform its own individual action. Now how to get the search query in the child Fragments?

Comment: What do you mean by `Access the Search Query`?Where is the code for that?

Comment: The Value that has been written in the search box....

Comment: You mean `EditText`?Is it in `Fragment`?

Comment: No deafault searchbox in the Actionbar ....

Comment: facing similar issue, isn't this solvable ???

Comment: @I-droid do you want communication between fragment to activity and vice-verse (i.e. pass value from activity to fragment and from fragment to activity)?

Comment: I just wanted to pass data from my `Activity` to `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    searchAction = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchAction.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // do your stuff with query
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // do something if needed
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You can send a query to your fragments via simple method call from activity.

Comment: I know this, but how to complete your sentence- "You can send a query to your fragments via simple method call from activity." ??? which is the main question.

Comment: Store your fragments as a fields in activity, make a superclass for fragments with accepting method, e.g. `public void accept(String query){//do your stuff}`. Call this method on your fragments when you need

Comment: I also have no idea how to do this,i'm completely lost. better if u can provide any sample. That would be great help.

Comment: Create a class `public class ParentFragment extends Fragment { protected String query;  public void accept(String query){this.query = query;}}` Then make all your fragments extend this class. Call `fragment.accept(query)` from `onQueryTextSubmit()`. You can also override `accept()` method in your fragments to add functionality (to not just store query, but do something else)

Comment: if i do what you said then i'm not able to change fragments in view. because then i getting `replace(int,id) not found for type parentFragment in line fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();`

Comment: Type names must be capitalised by convention: ParentFragment. About your error: you are able to change fragments, you just should do it right. It is hard to say from your message what's the problem, but looks like you're passing non-Fragment object to `replace()` method. Did you make a `ParentFragment` class extend `Fragment`? And all your fragments are now extending `ParentFragment`?

Comment: I have made a ParentFragment class extend Fragment and  all my fragments are  extending ParentFragment. then i'm unable to replace them as replace(int,id) not defined for type 'ParentFragment'. that is what my eclipse saying. Can you just try with above code in simple project ? because things not getting in favor of me. :(

Comment: `replace(int,id)` looks strange, do you have a class named `id`? `replace()` should accept any subtype of `Fragment` type (just as you passed your fragments, which extend Fragment, earlier), so it's definitely not the case. Look carefully in your code, error is somewhere else, I can't say more without information, sorry.

Comment: here id means a variable  of `ParentFragment` reference typre.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49674/discussion-between-dmide-and-i-droid)

Comment: I will contact you if i face any other issue due to this solution... Till then thank u very very much :)